# PgAdmin 4 not able to be contacted in server

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am attempting to run pgAdmin 4 on my laptop. I have got it to run once before with the help of a professional from Revature. He used Team Viewer to fix the issue hands on. He mentioned that there was a firewall issue but I have allowed pgAdmin to bypass the firewall. Unfortunately due to the policy, he cannot do that anymore hence why I am stuck in this predicament. Any help will be useful. Here are the steps that I have tried:

Specs:  postgresql-12.2-1-windows-x64 with pgAdmin4 included also pgAdmin 4 v4.18

1. Open Windows Explorer by opening any folder
2. In the address bar, type "%APPDATA%" and press Enter
3. Delete the "pgAdmin" folder in this directory
4. Start pgAdmin again

But still the issue is not resolved.

Next I tried this:

1. First, verify that your PostgreSQL database server is running by hitting `Ctrl+Alt+Delete`, opening the Task Manager, and then going to the "Services" tab.
   Pretty sure you're familiar with this process since you said you've done it before. Just find "postgresql-x64-XX" and make sure it's in Running status. If it's not, right-click and select "Start".
2. Then Go to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\web` (assuming you're using the latest version of PostgreSQL database and pgAdmin)
   3.Right-click "config-distro.py" and select "edit" or "Open With" -> Notepad.exe
3. Change "SERVER_MODE" from true to false and save
4. Clear the `%APPDATA%` cache for pgAdmin again
5. Start pgAdmin

Next I watched this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YvVPgTrYqU Explains how to run pgAdmin through Chrome. This didn't work.

Fatal Error `"The server could not be contacted."`

[image: Fatal Error "The server could not be contacted."]

I'm not sure what else to do at this point. The attached file is the error message that I keep getting. "Fatal Error. The server could not be contacted"

Comment: i'm really sorry but your question is not clear and i assume that you are trying to connect to the pg server using pgadmin where you get this error ?

Comment: Yes I am but i am constantly getting the Fatal Error. The server could not be contacted.

Comment: I get this error every time I attempt to run pgAdmin4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the PostgreSQL Service.
2. Delete the pgadmin folder from location: C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming
3. Install the new standalone pgadmin latest version from here: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v5.2/windows/.
   3.Re-start the Postgresql service.
4. Run the latest pgadmin version as "Administrator"(not the one which comes up with the PostgresSQl which might be you installed previously).
   Here you go..... :)